# Redux store is not updating when modifying element propriety of an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I have below code

```
case 'COMPLETE_TODO' :
state.todos[state.todos.findIndex((obj => obj.id == action.value))].status = "COMPLETED"
return {
   ...state,
   todos: state.todos
}
```

I feel like an array is not taken as a modified array because just a property of one single element has been updated.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do not mutate state, make a copy of state and then perform operations on it

Answer (score 2):

***Do not mutate state***, make a copy of state and then perform operations on it

```
case 'COMPLETE_TODO' :   
 return {
    ...state,
    todos: state.todos.map(obj=> ({...obj, status: obj.id == action.value ? "COMPLETED" : obj.status}))
 }
```

`map` create a new array, `...` spread syntax creates a shallow copy, if you object is deeper then one level, then you should do a deep clone,

For deep cloning you can use

```
 let deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.todos))
```